# How much RAM did the first version of Oregon Trail on the Apple II require?

Tags: history, apple-ii, memory, gaming

The later iterations of the series could have hundreds of kilobytes of RAM, but the original Apple II had 4K in the minimum configuration and 48K maximum (the latter using 16kbit chips which were still expensive in 1977).

Oregon Trail was one of the best-known games ever released for the machine; it has been said that nearly everyone who darkened the door of an American school during the heyday of the Apple II, played that game at least once.

There have been many subsequent versions of it (as well as previous versions on other platforms), but how much RAM did the first version of Oregon Trail on the Apple II require?

Answer (score 1):

The Apple II version required 64K:

[image: Oregon Trail Apple II back cover]

Back cover image from MobyGames.

The Apple II version came out in 1985 so 64K of RAM wasn't as a big of a requirement as it might sound. There were earlier text only versions of Oregon Trial, but it was this graphical version that most people would've played as students. While "thousands of school children" may have played the earlier text versions, it's this graphical edition that "nearly everyone who darkened the door of an American school during the heyday of the Apple II" played.

Comment: Good find, upvoted! But not quite what I'm looking for; as it says, that's the updated and expanded version that needs 64K, so it couldn't run on even a maxed out original Apple II. I'm looking for the memory requirement of the first Apple II version.

Comment: Ah! That's interesting; I didn't realize the version most people played, came out so late. So the best known version of the platform's best-known game, only got started in what was thought of by Apple itself as the twilight of the platform.

Comment: @rwallace, it looks like there were at least three versions for the Apple II: a 1978 port of the CDC Cyber 70 text version, a graphics-light 1980 release under the title *Oregon*, and the above 1985 release.

Comment: @rwallace The mid to late 80's was the heyday of the Apple II in schools. Before that they were too expensive and computers not thought of as important enough to be in wide use in every school, especially in the elementary and middle schools that this game targeted.